If a hacker succeeds in using my Apple ID to log his device into my iCloud account, can he spy on my devices well enough to hack into my web accounts?
I ask, assuming the latest versions of iOS and MacOS.
Can he capture keystrokes created on my devices?  Can he access my Google, Yahoo, etc website accounts if I'm logged into those sites, assuming he finds ways to overcome my two-factor authentication methods?
Can the Terminal app on one device execute commands to spy on another device, or even modify its software?
In particular, I wonder how Continuity features could be exploited.
Thank you for any insights!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you be a little more clear what you consider your Apple account?  What is the practical problem here that’s more focused than an open discussion about some generic and unspecified breach of your credentials (presumably)?


If a hacker succeeds in logging his device into my Apple account...

This boils down to what are your risks with a compromised Apple account.  It doesn't matter if they use their device or even your device for that matter.  Once the account is compromised, they can take full ownership of any and everything stored on that account.
See Can thieves with a stolen Macbook (non-M1) and corresponding AppleID iCloud password retrieve keychain and chrome passwords from the Mac? for a more in-depth look.  The bottom line is your risk profile is only as large or small as you make it.

Can the Terminal app on one device execute commands affecting another device?

This is like asking if a hammer or screwdriver from one toolbox affect the tools in another - it's irrelevant as exploits can be done via email, webpage, message app, etc.  Commands can be executed in a non-interactive shell never having brought up Terminal;  this is the wrong factor to focus on.  Instead, you should be focused on securing your data and having multiple layers of security such that if one is compromised, you don't immediately give up the keys to the kingdom.

In particular, I wonder how Continuity features could be exploited.

Continuity features are based in several underlying technologies like WiFi, BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) and iCloud identity services.  If these technologies are compromised, it means devices near or in your possession have been compromised.   Apple has an excellent write up on their platfom security; I highly suggest a thorough review.  Apple Platform Security

It is actually not true that once the account is compromised (by someone else logged in to the AppleID using email/password) that this means that they can take full ownership of everything stored on the account. For example access to the iCloud Keychain requires that the hacker's newly added device is approved physically on one of the existing devices already synced with Keychain - or alternatively, that the hacker also compromises the trusted phone number (for text messages) AND knows the passcode for the existing, trusted device.

@jksoegaard - I didn't say "devices associated with the account" but rather what's stored on the account.  There's a very clear distinction there.  I highly doubt a hacker who compromises an account is looking at add devices to it.

I think you might want to re-read the original question. The premise here is that a hacker added their own device to the compromised account. Regarding your distinction between "devices associated with the account" and "what's stored on the account" - I think you have misunderstood something there. The iCloud keychain is stored on the account. It is not true what you wrote in the answer, that a hacker that compromised the email/password of an AppleID can take ownership of everything stored on the account, as for example the iCloud keychain has additional protection.


Can the Terminal app on one device execute commands affecting another
device?

Depends on the firewall settings on the other device.

what harms can he do to my … iCloud items?

he/she can delete, download, add, or view anything from iCloud.  If Photo Library is on, this affects Photos on all devices.  Replace photos with child porn, make them public, and then tell law enforcement you have them?
I think (not certain) that Continuity features require both devices to be on the same WiFi.

If somebody hacks your AppleID and manages to add a device they have access to, they basically have access to everything synced via iCloud: documents, preferences, Safari bookmarks/history, keychains etc. If you store your website logins in a iCloud-enabled keychain, the attacker can access these as well.
They won‘t have access to your own devices, but they could use „Find my“ to lock and/or erase them.

It is actually not so that the iCloud-enabled keychain is just accessible simply adding a new device using the AppleID. The keychain has additional protection in place. This means that the hacker must trick the actual user into approving the new device from one of the old devices - or alternatively, he must be able to receive SMS messages sent to the user as well as knowing the pass code for the existing device (not the one the hacker added).

@jksoegaard Ah right, they may even need to trick to the user into accepting the initial attempt.
